# ngx-materialize: how to show validation errors on form submit?

Tags: angular, materialize, angular2-form-validation

All the examples on the page https://sherweb.github.io/ngx-materialize/form-validation have submit button disabled until form is valid. I would like to make it enabled and show validation errors on submit if there are any.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove [disabled]="form.valid" from the Submit Button Tag. You can control validation when user press submit button.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly change the value of  **pristine** key of the input field in the form variable just as the user tries to submit the form.
If your form is invalid execute `this.yourform.get('your_input_field').pristine = false;` for invalid field and error messages will be displayed immediately.